# WebClient in WP8.1

Tags: windows-phone, webclient

I'm trying to instantiate a WebClient inside a new WP8.1 project but for an unknown reason there is no WebClient class that I can instantiate.

For now I'll use HttpClient, but that is more lazy when it comes to getting data from server.

Could you please give me a suggestion?

Comment: Stick with `HttpClient`. It's designed to support asynchronous http requests. Is there a particular reason you don't like it?

Comment: Thinking about your question, I'm wondering if you are familiar with Async/Await. If not, here is one place you can start. It's a MUST know. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh464924.aspx

Comment: both HttpClient and WebClient are designed to support asynchronous http requests. For some reasons for another app that I was build for WP8 I am using WebClient because of request response speed.

Comment: What is your resistance to HttpClient though? I'm trying to understand the underlying question here.

Comment: There are also two versions of HttpClient in WP8.1 now.  System.Net.Http and Windows.Web.Http.  The second one is the better one to use because it supports progress.

Answer (score 1):

HttpClient is the mostly like as WebClient, you can encapsulate by yourself. Also, you can follow the [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25173792/which-httpclient-is-better-in-winrt-development) for more of the HttpClient.

Comment: Well, it's not *exactly* the same.  It's 100% async, for example.  But yes, it should be possible for a codebase to utilize `HttpClient` in an analogous fashion as `WebClient`.

Comment: Thanks for your remind, it's mostly like, but HttpClient is 100% async. I have updated my comments.