# Which Httpclient is better in WinRT development?

Tags: c#, .net, windows-runtime

In my progress of **winRt development**  i find that I can use both of the two HttpClient:

[System.Net.Http.HttpClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httpclient(v=vs.118).aspx)
[windows.web.http.httpclient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/windows/apps/windows.web.http.httpclient)

What's the difference and how can i choose one?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be using

```
windows.web.http.httpclient
```

for WinRT development as stated here.

> Note  The System.Net.Http and System.Net.Http.Headers namespace might
>   not be available in future versions of Windows for use by Windows
>   Store apps. Starting with Windows 8.1 and Windows Server 2012 R2, use
>   Windows.Web.Http.HttpClient in the Windows.Web.Http namespace and the
>   related Windows.Web.Http.Headers and Windows.Web.Http.Filters
>   namespaces instead for Windows Runtime apps.

Here is the [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh781239.aspx) from msdn.

Answer (score 0):

#1 is a .net function so it can only be used from .net languages (C# and VB.net), while #2 is from the Windows Runtime which means it can also be used from javascript store apps.

If you're using C# use whatever you like. My guess is #1 is calling #2